# Scipy/Pylab error.. Expected in: dynamic lookup?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

With a fresh build of Scipy/numpy/matplotlib on python 2.7 on OS X.  I am trying to `import pylab` but it doesn't seem to be working.  Why is this?

The error I'm getting is:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py",
> line 1, in <module>
>     from matplotlib.pylab import *   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py",

> line 216, in <module>
>     from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl.py",
> line 2, in <module>

>     from matplotlib import axis   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 10, in <module>

>     import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 52, in <module>

>     from matplotlib import ft2font ImportError:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so,

> 2): Symbol not found: _FT_Attach_File 

> Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
> Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Python that supports those packages is 2.6.x.  I am running them on 2.6.6.  You will need to additionally install Python 2.6.x on your machine to use these packages.  You can still keep your Python 2.7 and associated programs and run either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Clearing my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable solved the issue. Do:

```
$ unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The variable controls which directories the dynamic linker searches to find a given library. By default it is empty so there should be no harm in clearing it, unless you have some special setup. Check `man dyld` for reference.