# Error Expected in: dynamic lookup SimX

Tags: python-2.7

I am working with a package called SimX.  I followed the directions for installation but when I am trying to import the package I get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SIMX_example.py", line 4, in 
    import simx
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simx-0.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/simx/**init**.py", line 11, in 
    from core import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simx-0.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/simx/core/**init**.py", line 1, in 
    from core import *
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simx-0.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/simx/core/core.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNSdD0Ev
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simx-0.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/simx/core/core.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

I saw this answer: [Scipy/Pylab error.. Expected in: dynamic lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412617/scipy-pylab-error-expected-in-dynamic-lookup) but there is no mention of needing a particular installation of python and trying to clear the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH resulted in command not found.

Does anyone know the source of this error?